# Passing props from one class component to other in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking a beginner's course on react js. I came across class components and I wanted to know how does the `props` object get initialized.

for eg:

**Main Component:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header username="xyz"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Header:**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Welcome, {this.props.username}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I wanted to know does the `props` object in `Header` class is getting initialized?

Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super()
        this.props = props
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Welcome, {this.props.username}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

By using the above code I am a getting a message:

> ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before
> accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

My question is, if we want to pass anything to a class, shouldn't it be done using a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By extending React.Component, React does this for you.

The props object should never be changed inside the receiving component. React class components will gather all the arguments you pass to a component, and refer to them by the common name "props". This is why you don't have to do it yourself, in the constructor.

However, in modern React, class components are rarely used. The reason is that class components easily ends up with complicated lifecycle management.

The Header component, written as a function rather than a class, would look like this:

```
const Header = (props) => (
  <div>
      <p>Welcome, {props.username}</p>
  </div>
)
```

It is also very common to destructure props directly, so that you never really access the props object, like this:

```
const Header = ({username}) => (
  <div>
      <p>Welcome, {username}</p>
  </div>
)
```

In the case of function components, you're free to use whatever name you want for the props. I wouldn't do it though, because people are used to props being called props. But this would work as well:

```
const Header = (params) => (
  <div>
      <p>Welcome, {params.username}</p>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the same code as you post without constructor and I don't have any error.

You can pass what you want to a class without using a constructor like you did in your example code.

I share the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-stallman-cu1pub?file=/src/index.js) of your code in sandbox.
I put the constructor in Header to show that it returns the same with it and without it.

Comment: What I am asking is why isn't it working when I add a constructor. In other languages like java, whenever I want to pass some data to another class I always use a constructor, why isn't it working here when I pass `props` to the constructor of the `Header` class.

Comment: The other question is how does `Header` class know about the `props` object?

Comment: In the link that I shared, it works with a constructor. Did you tried putting ";" after `super()` and `this.props=props` ?

Comment: Ok it works now. The other question I had was how the `Header` class knows about `props` object if I don't pass it through the constructor?

Comment: Because the data that you send from the *parent* class (in your case the username) to *child* class (in your case the Header class) is defined as a props data for default by React. It works with components and the data that you send throught them is defined as props. (Sorry for my English, I tried to explain making it easy to understand)